# Reading a File's Line with no Spaces into separate Variables

Tags: c++

First time asking a question on this site, so here goes. I've been racking my brain for quite some time, but still can't seem to find the answer to this.

Let's say I have a file that reads as follows:

```
    123456789John       Doe        0001111.11
    925219042Mary       Jane       0000302.54
    891492829Gertrude   Marisou    0123467.76
```

How would I separate say, 123456789 and John into their own respective strings for input into a vector containing four variables? (`Std::string`, `Std::string`, `Std::string`, `Double`)

Here is my current code if you all would like to take a peek at it and tell me where I am going wrong.

```
#pragma once
#if !defined(__Account7_h__)
#define __Accoun7_h__

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
//Personal file for trimming the extra whitespace
#include "Trim.h"



class Account7 {
private:
    std::string account_code;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    double balance;



public:
    //Getters, Setters, Initialization List and whatnot.


    //On a separate file
#if !defined(__Vmanager7_h__)
#define __Vmanager7_h__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "Account7.h"
#include "Trim.h"

    using namespace generic;
    class Vmanager7 {
    public:

        int a = 1;
        std::ifstream infile;
        std::ofstream outputFile;

        std::vector<Account7> _Account;
        Account7 temp;

        std::string Empl;
        std::string scapeg;
        std::string acc_c;
        std::string fname;
        std::string lname;
        double bal;




        int Managed() {
            int count;

            infile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

            try {
                infile.open("account.dat", std::ifstream::in);
            }
            catch (std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
                std::cout << "File is not opening" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
            infile.exceptions(std::ios::goodbit);
            while (getline(infile, Empl)) {
                count = 1;
                std::istringstream ss(Empl);
                while (getline(ss, scapeg)) {
                    if (count == 1)
                        acc_c = scapeg;
                    else if (count == 2)
                        fname = scapeg;
                    else if (count == 3)
                        lname = scapeg;
                    else
                        bal = atof(scapeg.c_str());
                    count++;

                }

                temp.setac(acc_c);
                temp.setfn(fname);
                temp.setln(lname);
                temp.setba(bal);



                _Account.push_back(temp);

            }
            infile.close();

            outputFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

            try {
                outputFile.open("Aoutput.dat");
            }
            catch (std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
                std::cout << "File opening fail" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
            outputFile.exceptions(std::ios::goodbit);

            for (int i = 0; i < _Account.size(); i++) {


                std::cout << _Account[i].getac() << " " << _Account[i].getfn() << " " << _Account[i].getln() << " " << _Account[i].getba();
                bal = _Account[i].getba();
                bal -= int(bal);
                if (bal == 0)
                    std::cout << ".00";
                std::cout << '\n';


            }


            outputFile.close();

        }
    };
};
```

The output I get is something along the lines of this:

```
    123456789John       Doe        0001111.11   -9.25596e+61
    925219042Mary       Jane       0000302.54   -9.25596e+61
    191492829Gertrude   Marisou    0123467.76   -9.25596e+61
```

I would like the output to look just like the input. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: `scanf("%9s%11s%8s%d%e", &number, &surname, &name, &dec, &sci);`

Comment: `std::getline()` always expects to read a newline-terminated string. Even when reading from a `std::stringstream`. Since your std::stringstream does not contain newlines, the first call to `std:getline() will swallow the entire line, again. Use the `>>` operator instead of the inner `std::getline()` loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think I somewhat understand what you are saying, but for my edification's sake, could you please elaborate further? How, specifically, would your write the loop if you aren't going to use getline? Will it actually understand the information I want separated if I only use the >> operator?

Comment: As long as there's at least one space between the fields, and the fields themselves do not contain spaces. You don't really need a loop, but you can certainly still have one. The `>>` operator would be called exactly like `getline()`. Instead of `while (getline(ss, scapeg))`, it would be `while (ss >> scapeg)`. It's really not more complicated than that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah. Well the issue I'm having is that account_code and first_name does not have a space to separate them. If they had a space in between them, I would have finished this project a while ago. haha Do you know how I would get then information even without a space? You may have already answered it, but I just can't seem to grasp the concept.

Comment: In that case, use `std::string`'s `substr()` method, to precisely extract each part of the string.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are literally the best thing since sliced bread. I don't know what I never thought of that! Now there's only one issue left. The file isn't reading the last field properly. It definitely has to do with how the last field is a double. So I tried using this code:
        bal = std::stod(scapeg.c_str());
to convert it into a double, but all it does is output that weird code (the file address?) instead of the intended double. Do you know how I'd fix this? Sorry for all the questions by the way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nevermind. Figured it out. You're the absolute best.